# Best strategy after losing GPG/PGP key passphrase (but still access to YubiKey)

Tags: encryption, gnupg, password-recovery, pgp, yubikey

When I got my first YubiKey several years ago, I created a new GPG key specifically for it. After uploading the private key to the YubiKey (`keytocard`), I also stored an armored copy of the private key file in a secure location.

**What I still have today:**

- YubiKey with privkey on it (I can still sign / encrypt / decrypt)
- The backup of the private + public key files
- Revocation certificate

**What I lost:**

- Passphrase for the armored private key file backup

The YubiKey is showing signs of age (e.g., doesn't always activate) and I stopped trusting it, so now I'm wondering what to do with the GPG key while Yubi is still working.

Is there a way to recover the passphrase, other than brute force, so I can migrate the GPG key to a new YubiKey? I already tried cracking the privkey with `john` on a GPU cluster, but that failed.

If not, would be the best strategy to create a new key, sign it with my old key, and then revoke the old key?